# Cloudant With Lucene Search Fails To Sort As Expected

Tags: java, sorting, lucene, cloudant

I am pretty new to Cloudant but have developed in SQL on DB2 for some time. I am running into an issue where I *think I am using the Lucene query engine and Cloudant indexes to return results from my query.  The query gets all the results I want however, they are not sorted correctly.  I am wanting to sort the results alphabetically based on the "officialName" field. Because we are only returning the first 21 out of n results (and then we have a js handler to call more results via paging) we cannot sort in the java side but must do so via Cloudant. Our application is running Java and executed using IBM's Bluemix and WebSphere Liberty Profile. I have packaged the cloudant-client-2.8.0.jar and cloudant-HTTP-2.8.0.jar files to access the Cloudant database. We have many queries that are working so the connection itself is fine.

Here is the code that builds the Cloudant Client search object:

```
Search search = getCloudantDbForOurApp().search("bySearchPP-ddoc/bySearchPP-indx").includeDocs(true);
SearchResult<DeliverableDetails> result = search.sort(getSortJsonString(searchString)).querySearchResult(getSearchQuery(searchString), DeliverableDetails.class);
```

Here is the method getSortJsonString. It should be noted that the search string is typically NOT null.  I should also note that leaving in or taking out the -score attribute does effect the search but never achieves alpha sorted results.

```
private String getSortJsonString(String searchString) {
    String sortJson;
    if (searchString != null && !searchString.isEmpty()) {
        sortJson = "[\"-<score>\",\"officialName<string>\"]";
    } else {
        sortJson = "\"officialName<string>\"";
    }
    return sortJson;
}
```

Here is the getSearchQuery method's relevant code for reference:

```
...
query += "(";
query += "officialName:" + searchString + "^3";
query += " OR " + "deliverableName:" + searchString + "^3";
query += " OR " + "alias:" + searchString + "^3";
query += " OR " + "contact:" + searchString;
query += ")";
....
// The query will look like below, where<search_string> is some user inputted value
// (officialName:<search_string>*^3 OR deliverableName:<search_string>*^3 OR alias:<search_string>*^3 OR contact:<search_string>*)
```

I have setup a design doc and index using the Cloudant dashboard as follows:

```
{
"_id": "_design/bySearchPP-ddoc",
"_rev": "4-a91fc4ddeccc998c58adb487a121c168",
"views": {},
"language": "javascript",
"indexes": {
  "bySearchPP-indx": {
    "analyzer": {
      "name": "perfield",
      "default": "standard",
      "fields": {
        "alias": "simple",
        "contact": "simple",
        "deploymentTarget": "keyword",
        "businessUnit": "keyword",
        "division": "keyword",
        "officialName": "simple",
        "deliverableName": "simple",
        "pid": "keyword"
      }
    },
    "index": "function(doc) {
              if (doc.docType === \"Page\") {
                index(\"officialName\", doc.officialName, {\"store\":true, \"boost\":4.0});
                index(\"deliverableName\", doc.deliverableName, {\"store\":true, \"boost\":3.0});
                if (doc.aliases) {
                  for (var i in doc.aliases) {
                    index(\"alias\", doc.aliases[i], {\"store\":true, \"boost\":2.0});
                  }
                }
                if (doc.allContacts) {
                  for (var j in doc.allContacts) {
                    index(\"contact\", doc.allContacts[j], {\"store\":true, \"boost\":0.5});
                    }
                }
                index(\"deploymentTarget\", doc.deploymentTarget, {\"store\":true});
                index(\"businessUnit\", doc.businessUnit, {\"store\":true});
                index(\"division\", doc.division, {\"store\":true});
                index(\"pid\", doc.pid.toLowerCase(), {\"store\":true});
             }
          }"
     }
   }
 }
```

I am not sure if the sort is working and just not working how I want it to or if I have misconfigured something.  Either way, any help would be greatly appreciated. -Doug

Comment: In one case you are sorting by score first and then officialName. This is not the issue?

Comment: You can look at the order on [SearchResultRow](http://static.javadoc.io/com.cloudant/cloudant-client/2.2.0/com/cloudant/client/api/model/SearchResult.SearchResultRow.html) to see the values used in the sort. The first value in the array for each row corresponds to the first value used in the sort.

for (Object obj : row.getOrder()) {
   System.out.println(obj);
}

Comment: @markwatsonatx - It wasn't working whether I took out the score tag or not. Thanks for he debug tip.  That showed that the officialName value wasn't being returned.  Did some digging and I found out that the field was indexed but should NOT have been tokenized. When I changed the index form simple analyzer to keyword it worked!  Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my own issue w/ help from comments above.  Apparently everything was setup correctly but once I debug per @markwatsonatx I could see the field I wanted wasn't being returned.  Did some digging online and apparently for sort the field must be both indexed and NOT tokenized.  Thus I checked my index and noticed that the filed was being analyzed by the Simple analyzer. Changed it to the Keyword and the sort works as expected. Hoep this helps someone.